# Computing the most representative sample of a random variable

Tags: algorithms, distance, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable and $n > 0$. Using numerical methods, how can we find the vector $\vec v$ of $n$ real numbers that is most characteristic of $X$, in the sense that the empirical distribution of $\vec v$ is closest to the distribution of $X$? To make this concrete, we could try minimizing the [earth mover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) between the empirical distribution and the distribution of $X$ (or equivalently, I think, $\int |F_{X}(x) - F_{\vec v}(x)| dx$, where $F_X$ is the CDF of $X$ and $F_{\vec v}$ is the empirical CDF of $\vec v$).

The idea here is to find the single "most representative" sample of size $n$ from $X$. I don't have any applications in mind. I'm just curious.

A brute-force approach would be to use a generic optimization algorithm like R's `optim` to choose $\vec v$. Is there a slicker way?

Comment: It comes down to what you mean by "closest to." For instance, when proximity is measured by the maximum absolute difference between the two distribution functions, the solution is incredibly simple -- just use the quantiles $1/(n+1), 2/(n+1),\ldots,n/(n+1).$

Comment: @whuber Yes, that's why I brought up EMD in the following sentence.